# Highlighting in SolrNet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, solr, highlighting, solrnet

I have a problem to get highlighting working. I use a ASP.Net MVC Application with a WCF Service. The WCF Service return the results to the view. My code is:

```
public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> SolrQuery(string searchString)
    {
        SolrInitialSetup(); 

        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SolrPDFDocument>>();

        var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("author", searchString),
            new QueryOptions
            {
                Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
                {
                    Fields = new[] { "search_snippet" },
                }
            });

        var returnedResults = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var pdfDoc in results)
            {
                var docBuffer = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                docBuffer.Add("Id", ""+pdfDoc.Id.GetHashCode());
                docBuffer.Add("Content", "" + pdfDoc.Content.ElementAt(0));
                docBuffer.Add("Version", "" + pdfDoc.Version);

                foreach (var h in results.Highlights[results[0].Id])
                {
                    docBuffer.Add("search_snippet", String.Format("{0}", string.Join(", ", h.Value.ToArray())));
                    Debug.WriteLine("search_snippet", String.Format("{0}", string.Join(", ", h.Value.ToArray())));
                }
                returnedResults.Add(docBuffer);
            }
        }
        return returnedResults;
    }
```

@ Line `foreach (var h in results.Highlights[results[0].Id])` I get an error in the browser `The given key was not present in the dictionary.` I have no idea whats wrong.

My schema.xml:

```
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
    <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="search_snippet" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />
```

My SolrPDFDocument.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SolrNet.Attributes;

namespace WcfSearchService
{
    class SolrPDFDocument
    {
        [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [SolrField("author")]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        [SolrField("content")]
        public ICollection<string> Content { get; set; }

        [SolrField("search_snippet")]
        public ICollection<string> SearchSnippet { get; set; }

        [SolrField("_version_")]
        public long Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>

     <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
       <str name="hl">on</str>
       <str name="hl.fl">search_snippet author content</str>
     </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i have solved my problem.

Instead of using the sample code like that:

```
var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("author", searchString),
        new QueryOptions
        {
            Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
            {
                Fields = new[] { "author" },
            }
        });
```

I set the Parameter of the new Fields like this:

```
var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("text", searchString),
        new QueryOptions
        {
            Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
            {
                Fields = new[] { "*" },
            }
        });
```

So I'm getting all the snippets to all results. Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Yes, this is what I was saying in my first comment in my original answer. You need to specify all of the fields that you want snippets for. I am not sure that using "*" is the best approach. Try using `{ "search_snippet", "author", "content" }` to match your solrconfig.xml setting.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be getting any highlight results at all. Can you debug your code and validate that `results.Highlights` is populated. Also check your highlighting defaults settings as I believe you need to set hl=true not on.

```
 <str name="hl">true</str>
```

Comment: <str name="hl">true</str> and <str name="hl">on</str> is the same i think. I get results but in the results.Highlightings are only Keys stored and the snippets are empty.

Comment: I get an error in that line of code foreach (var h in results.Highlights[results[0].Id]) => The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Have you verified that this same query directly against Solr is returning highlighting results? Because, by setting the HighlightingParameters in the SolrNet QueryOptions, you are only returning/requesting highlights for the "search_snippet" field. Because it is being passed in the query it is overriding the settings in your solrconfig.xml. If you want snippets for the other fields as well, add those to the Fields HighlightingParameters in your code.

Comment: I have execute var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("author", searchString)); and now I'm getting Sippets in the results.Highlights. So I overwrite the correct HighlightingParameters with some wrong values. But i don't know were the problem is? I want to use the SolrNet parameters to handle my queries!

Comment: Sounds like your problem was that your query was either not finding any matching results, or there were not any highlights for the query results that were returned, which is quite possible. So long as you pass the parameters you desire to use with SolrNet, you should not have any problems, as the parameters passed with the query will always override any default settings in the solrconfig.xml.

Comment: The query returnes the results correctly. But in the result.Highlights is only the Key to each result stored and the Value holds SolrNet.Impl.HighlightedSnippets with a Count of 0. The default settings in the solrconfig.xml works fine i get to the same seach String the Snippets i want. I think its a C# SolrNet problem of my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. For me, this wasn't working (I wasn't getting any results):

```
var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("text", searchString),
        new QueryOptions
        {
            Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
            {
                Fields = new[] { "*" },
            }
        });
```

But, this works for me:

```
 var results = solr.Query(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "text", searchString),
            new QueryOptions
            {
                Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
                {
                    Fields = new[] { "*" },
                }
            });
```

I am using solr 4.6.0 and SolrNet build #173 (16 Oct 13 00:32)